# Formating issue with <p> and <img> inside of a <div>

Tags: html, css, format, margin, padding

**Problem:**
[image]

I'm making a heading for a website. I want both the picture and the name of my website in my header.

The problem is that the text is being very ugly. I want to push the text upwards so its centered.

---

**How I think the problem would be solved:**

I suspect the answer has something to do with `padding` or `margin` but all my attempts at fixes don't do anything.

---

**My Code:**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Camels</title>
        <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="main-pannel">
                <img id="logo" src="http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/assets/10972047/camel.jpg">
                <p id="title">Camelsgggg</p>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}
#header {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #992e0c;
    height:100px;
    width:fill-available;
}

.main-pannel:hover{
    background-color: #cecece;
}
#logo{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#title{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000;
}
```

---

Any help is appreciated! :) ~Gunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this title css, using transform to move it via css.

```
#title{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

To move it to the right, you can always use translateX also.

Comment: what language/library are -webkit and -ms from? This works (thanks) but I have no clue what those two lines of code do...

Comment: There are from normal CSS codes, but work differently from how each browser views it, hence to be safe, apply it to all browsers. . you can play with it here 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_translate

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a spelling mistake in the class `<div class="main-pannel">`.  Guess it should be `main-panel`.

Second, define `line-height:100px;` css equivalent to the div height of the text-containing element. In your case, it should be `main-panel`.  That should push the text in the middle.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sunalive/cx61z18p/1/

Comment: Do I add line-height:100px into #header? Doing that actually moves it further down.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle link I have pasted.  you should add it to the `main-panel` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I used a the float technique and added a bit of padding.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="main-pannel">
            <img id="logo" src="http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/assets/10972047/camel.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main-title">
            <p id="title">Camelsgggg</p>
       </div>
    </div>           
</body>



body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

   }



#header {

    background-color: #992e0c;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
   }

   .main-panel:hover{
    background-color: #cecece;
   }
   #logo{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
#title{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.main-title {
  float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pnL2xdne/